# how to send keystrokes to bluetooth connected iphone in cocoa app

Tags: iphone, cocoa, bluetooth

I need to send keystrokes to bluetooth connected iPhone from cocoa app,just like "TypeToPhone" app is doing. Please let me know how i can do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is no easy task. I know, because I am one of the developers behind Type2Phone.

Type2Phone does have AppleScript support though. Depending on your needs, you could funnel characters through Type2Phone to your iPhone.

Comment: HI, it's g8 having your reply...I'll check and see how much i can do with the existing type2phone scripting feature. I am wondering if I'll get some clue to do my own research, as i know this is not going to be simple for me, but i at least get something new to learn!!:)